# URL doesn't appear in correct index of UITableview after parsing

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

while parsing collection of dictionary array json thats look like below

```
{
"responsecode": "200",
"responsemsg": "Product List",
"total_pages_count": "35",
"data": [
{
  "pk_productid": 412,
  "fk_userid": 59,
  "productname": "Cerulean",
  "sku": "man-cerulean412",
  "description": "",
  "shortdescription": "",
  "prodsaletype": 1,
  "prodprice": 156000,
  "is_approve": 1,
  "issold": false,
  "issoldprice": 0,
  "isbid": 0,
  "lastbidprice": 156000,
  "isdiscount": false,
  "isfixeddiscount": false,
  "discountamt": 0,
  "ispromocode": false,
  "isonline": false,
  "iscash": true,
  "images": [
    {
      "imagepath": "http://www.artively.com/Upload/ProdColorThumbImage/270120161832_Cerulean_Fotor.jpg",
      "imgvideotype": 1
    }
  ],
  "videos": [],
  "first_name": "Manhar ",
  "last_name": "Kapadiya",
  "totalhour": 0,
  "totalminute": 0,
  "totalsecond": 0,
  "is_auction_onhold": "1",
  "bid_user_id": 0,
  "bid_first_name": "",
  "bid_last_name": "",
  "bid_user_image": "Upload/ThubUserProfile/noimage.jpg",
  "is_fav": 0,
  "share_url": "http://www.artively.com/url/5dd129",
  "share_count": 0,
  "category_id": 0,
  "category_name": "",
  "issubmited": false
},
....
..
.
```

I am able to get the value of image url and other details but while showing it on UITableview it does not appear on a proper index for example

Tableview index 1 - it shows the product name and prod.price but the image url is shown in the next tableview index ie -2

Tableview index 2 - it show the image url of first index were as the product name and price are nil

Tableview index 3 -  it shows the product name and prod.price but the image url is shown in the next tableview index ie -4

and continue like this...

Here is my code

```
func parseJSONData(data: NSData) -> [ProductDetails] {
    var product_Detail = [ProductDetails]()
    do {
            let jsonResult = try     NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as? NSDictionary

         let jsonProductDetails = jsonResult?["data"] as! [AnyObject]
     print("the json response is",jsonProductDetails)

        for jsonproductDetail in jsonProductDetails{
            let productDetail = ProductDetails()

            productDetail.productAuthor = jsonproductDetail["first_name"]as! String
            productDetail.productPrice =  jsonproductDetail["prodprice"]as! Int


            product_Detail.append(productDetail)



           let jsonResult = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as? NSArray
           let jsonProductImageDetails = jsonproductDetail["images"] as! [AnyObject]
           print("the json response is",jsonProductImageDetails)

      //Where to make a loop to get the desired result 
          for jsonproductImage in jsonProductImageDetails{
               let product_Image = ProductDetails()
               product_Image.productImages = jsonproductImage["imagepath"] as! String
               product_Detail.append(product_Image)


           }

        }
    }
    catch {
        print (error)
    }
    self.parseJSONImage(data)
    return product_Detail

}
```

Model

```
class ProductDetails {
    var productAuthor: String!
    var productPrice: Int!
    var artImages: String!
}
```

Displaying cell images

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cellIdentifier = "Cell"
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UserHomeScreenTableViewCell

    // Configure the cell...
    cell.artsAuthorName.text = globalArr[indexPath.row].productAuthor
    cell.priceLabel.text = "\(globalArr[indexPath.row].productPrice)"  //to convert string value to interger
    let productDetailsObject = globalArr[indexPath.row].artImages
    print("@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@",productDetailsObject)





    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), {

        if let url = NSURL(string: self.globalArr[indexPath.row].artImages.imagepath) {
            if let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url) {
                if let image = UIImage(data: data) {
                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { () -> Void in
                        cell.artImageView.image = image
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    })

    return cell
}
```

Comment: can you please include code of your ProductDetails class ?

Comment: based on that I will rewrite the function parseJSONData()

Comment: Sir i have updated the code for  ProductDetails class , if it need to be change please suggest..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Model Classes.**

```
class ProductDetails {
    var productAuthor: String!
    var productPrice: Int!
    var artImages: [ArtImage]!
}

class ArtImage {
    var imagepath: String!
    var imgvideotype: Int!
}
```

**we will store the array of `ArtImage` as property of `ProductDetails`.**
Simillarly you can create other class for **`videos`** also
So you can use it as below.

```
let productDetailsObject = //value of your ProductDetails object
let imagePath = productDetailsObject.artImages[0].imagepath
```

**Rewrite the function as follow.**

```
func parseJSONData(data: NSData) -> [ProductDetails] {
    var product_Detail = [ProductDetails]()


    do {
        let jsonResult = try     NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as? NSDictionary

        let jsonProductDetails = jsonResult?["data"] as! [AnyObject]
        print("the json response is",jsonProductDetails)

        for jsonproductDetail in jsonProductDetails{
            let productDetail = ProductDetails()

            productDetail.productAuthor = jsonproductDetail["first_name"]as! String
            productDetail.productPrice =  jsonproductDetail["prodprice"]as! Int

            //we will fetch the images from first object, i.e. from the jsonproductDetail
            let jsonProductImageDetails = jsonproductDetail["images"] as! [AnyObject]
            var artImagesModelArray  = [ArtImage]()
            for image in jsonProductImageDetails {
                let artImage = ArtImage();
                artImage.imagepath = image["imagepath"] as! String
                artImage.imgvideotype = image["imgvideotype"] as! Int
                artImagesModelArray.append(artImage)
            }
            productDetail.artImages = artImagesModelArray;

            product_Detail.append(productDetail)
        }
    }
    catch {
        print (error)
    }
    return product_Detail
}
```

Comment: Thank you sir, now everything is working but still when i use the url to display image in uitableview  it gives me error!!!   any suggestion :)

Comment: if let url = NSURL(string: self.globalArr[indexPath.row].artImages.imagepath) { }

Comment: use : if let url = NSURL(string: self.globalArr[indexPath.row].artImages[0].imagepath)

Comment: sir the above code will show only one image right .. but i have to show all the fetched url images   sir i have updated the code "Displaying cell images" section kindly have a look

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102773/discussion-between-hitendra-hckr-and-kk002able).

Answer (score 0):

1. Change your code with   func parseJSONData(data: NSData) ->
   [ProductDetails] {
           var product_Detail = ProductDetails
           do {
                   let jsonResult = try   NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options:
       NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as? NSDictionary

   ```
            let jsonProductDetails = jsonResult?["data"] as! [AnyObject]

           for jsonproductDetail in jsonProductDetails {
               let productDetail = ProductDetails()`
              let jsonProductImageDetails = jsonProductDetails["images"] as! [AnyObject]

               productDetail.productAuthor = jsonproductDetail["first_name"]as! String
               product.Detail.productImages = jsonProductImageDetails["imagepath"] as! String
               productDetail.productPrice =  jsonproductDetail["prodprice"]as! Int
               product_Detail.append(productDetail)
           }
       }
       catch {
           print (error)
       }
       self.parseJSONImage(data)
       return product_Detail }
   ```